# I need to deploy a multipart dockerized application to fly.io

Tags: docker-compose, fly

I have a dockerized app that has 3 levels, a frontend with React, a backend with Django/Python, and a database with postgres.

So, in the root directory there’s a docker-compose.yml file instead of a simple Dockerfile, the frontend service has its own Dockerfile, as well as the backend service, and the database level doesn’t have a Dockerfile, but it is working with the postgres image downloaded from Docker.

I created a fly.toml file in the root directory made from my docker-compose.yml file, this is the fly.toml file:

(the images there are the real images produced from doing docker-compose up --build)

```
app = "my app name"
org = "my organization"

[[services]]
  internal_port = 5432
  protocol = "tcp"
  [services.concurrency]
    hard_limit = 1
  [services.env]
    POSTGRES_USER = "my user"
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD = "my password"
    POSTGRES_DB = "menu_db"

[[services]]
  internal_port = 8000
  protocol = "tcp"
  [services.concurrency]
    hard_limit = 2
  [[services.ports]]
    handlers = ["http"]
    port = "8000"
  # Add any environment variables needed for your API service
  image = "docker-whole-menu-api:latest"

[[services]]
  internal_port = 3000
  protocol = "tcp"
  [services.concurrency]
    hard_limit = 1
  [[services.ports]]
    handlers = ["http"]
    port = "3000"
  # Add any environment variables needed for your web service
  image = "docker-whole-menu-web:latest"
```

My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: docker-whole-menu-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: <my user>
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <my password>
      POSTGRES_DB: menu_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - my_network

  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: docker-whole-menu-api
    command: sh -c "./wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- python backend/manage.py migrate && python backend/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./api/backend:/app/api/backend
    networks:
      - my_network

  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: docker-whole-menu-web
    command: npm run serve
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

When I try to deploy, fly deploy asks for a Dockerfile in the root, but there’s a docker-compose file, what do you suggest me to do?

This is what I get:

```
fly deploy
==> Verifying app config
Validating C:\WebDev\menu-app-project\docker-whole-menu\fly.toml
Platform: machines
✓ Configuration is valid
--> Verified app config
==> Building image
Remote builder fly-builder-muddy-mountain-4150 ready
Error: failed to fetch an image or build from source: app does not have a Dockerfile or buildpacks configured. See https://fly.io/docs/reference/configuration/#the-build-section
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like they don't support multi container apps you gotta individually host  everything how misleading lol

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35555432)